# What KPIs can we measure for a BPM tool other than time to complete the process

Tags: project-planning, business-process-management, kpi

I am working on a BPM tool were i can define SLA for each workflow in regards to the time needed to complete the whole process and each activity within the process. but my question is what other KPI can a BPM system have other than the optimal time to complete the whole process . 
In my case the KPI is the "maximum time to complete a process" and then i define the SLA to be 10 hours.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, you may record all information you need, temporal or business information. Then, what information the tool allow you to access depends on what this system supports.
The BPMS I know best is bonita where you can access temporal informations (time someone pass on a task, time waited for a task, if the task is late, how long a case take to finish, ...), process informations (candidates, choices made, ...) and even business data.

Hope it helps